# Different targets for end to end tests in protractor

Tags: angular, protractor, e2e-testing, angularjs-e2e

How to run end to end test cases for Protractor for a angular workspace which has multiple applications. For example, here is the sample structure

```
-/angularRootFolder
   -apps
      -First app
        -e2e
          -pageobjects
          -testcases
       -Second app
          -e2e
          -pageobjects
          -testcases
```

How to define this in the root Protractor config file ?
Any help would be greatly appreciated! I would want to run this setup in Jenkins instance too. Angular version: 5.0.0- rc2

Comment: Is this for AngularJS or Angular 2? Please edit the tags accordingly.

Comment: Sure. It's for Angular 5 rc2

Answer (score 0):

The root folder, should automatically be "e2e", from the outside of the config file.
In order to run different specs for Protractor JS end 2 end testing, if you have multiple config files, then it should be fairly easy. set a config, for each app.

if you have a single config file, then you should use test suites.

```
 suites: {
        sw: ['e2e-tests/s/*accept-s.spec.js','e2e-tests/s/*s-week.spec.js', 'e2e-tests/s/*deny-s.spec.js'],
        sp: 'e2e-tests/**/*sp.spec.js'

    },
```

running them:

```
protractor tests\e2e-tests.conf.js --suite=sw
```

or

```
protractor tests\e2e-tests.conf.js --suite=sp
```

Comment: I have a protractor.conf.js in the root directory, i don't have any config files in the e2e directories of First app and Second app.

Comment: you can save the config file wherever you want, and you have to specify the test suite, for each application. and trough the same config file, you can test as many applications as you want.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. You need to use `ng e2e --app=FirstApp` (or) `ng e2e --app=SecondApp`
By doing this, you can exclusively run e2e tests for respective apps.